# generate random double numbers in c++

Tags: c++, random

How to generate random numbers between two doubles in c++ , these numbers should look like xxxxx,yyyyy .

Comment: "these number should look like xxxxx,yyyyy". How to generate random doubles, and how to format doubles as strings, are completely separate issues.

Comment: And come to think of it alternatively: generating evenly-distributed *doubles* and generating evenly-distributed *decimals* are somewhat different, although related, tasks.

Comment: Generating evenly-distributed integers is more closely related to the decimals problem.

Comment: Short update in year 2022: for a brief and competent introduction to pseudo-random number generation in C++11 and beyond, see chapter 24.7 in [the latest C++ programming textbook by Bjarne Stroustrup](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), ISBN 978-0321-992789. For a full exposure, the official “Random Number Generation in C++11” N3551 White Paper, 12 pages only, can be obtained [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf). The paper starts with a short discussion of the historical shortcomings of the **legacy** `rand()` and `srand()` functions.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Here's how

```
double fRand(double fMin, double fMax)
{
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}
```

Remember to call srand() with a proper seed each time your program starts.

[Edit]
This answer is obsolete since C++ got it's native non-C based random library (see Alessandro Jacopsons answer) 
But, this still applies to C

Comment: If you add 1 to RAND_MAX, do so carefully, since it might be equal to INT_MAX. `double f = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);`

Comment: Note that the randomness of this can be limited. The range xxxxx,yyyyy suggests 10 decimal digits. There are plenty of systems where RAND_MAX is smaller than 10^10. This would mean that some numbers in that range have `p(xxxxx,yyyyy)==0.0`

Comment: You should avoid rand() if possible. See the other answer for a C++11 or TR1 solution.

Comment: Not everyone uses C++0x, tr1 or C++11
Is there any reference that shows rand() is to be avoided? It's been the only way to get random numbers for decades.

Comment: Here is one resource (a video of a talk): http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful.  rand() is not thread-safe, it may not produce a uniform distribution (depending on implementation), and mod-dividing the output will give a non-uniform distribution if not careful.  Better to use modern tools unless you have a reason to avoid them.

Comment: What is the library to be included to this for work, I'm getting ‘rand’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @ChamilaWijayarathna, You need to include cstdlib

Comment: I think this is not enough distributed in 2^sizeof(double) since sizeof(int)<sizeof(double), i.e., it is not really random!

Answer (score 133):

This solution requires C++11 (or TR1).

```
#include <random>

int main()
{
   double lower_bound = 0;
   double upper_bound = 10000;
   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(lower_bound,upper_bound);
   std::default_random_engine re;
   double a_random_double = unif(re);

   return 0;
}
```

For more details see John D. Cook's ["Random number generation using C++ TR1"](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html).

See also Stroustrup's ["Random number generation"](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-random).

Comment: You might want to update this with a more recent [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) document, which is pretty good.

Answer (score 16):

This should be performant, thread-safe and flexible enough for many uses:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Numeric, typename Generator = std::mt19937>
Numeric random(Numeric from, Numeric to)
{
    thread_local static Generator gen(std::random_device{}());

    using dist_type = typename std::conditional
    <
        std::is_integral<Numeric>::value
        , std::uniform_int_distribution<Numeric>
        , std::uniform_real_distribution<Numeric>
    >::type;

    thread_local static dist_type dist;

    return dist(gen, typename dist_type::param_type{from, to});
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    for(auto i = 0U; i < 20; ++i)
        std::cout << random<double>(0.0, 0.3) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If accuracy is an issue here you can create random numbers with a finer graduation by randomizing the significant bits.
Let's assume we want to have a double between 0.0 and 1000.0.

On MSVC (12 / Win32) RAND_MAX is 32767 for example.

If you use the common `rand()/RAND_MAX` scheme your gaps will be as large as

```
1.0 / 32767.0 * ( 1000.0 - 0.0) = 0.0305 ...
```

In case of IEE 754 double variables (53 significant bits) and 53 bit randomization the smallest possible randomization gap for the 0 to 1000 problem will be

```
2^-53 * (1000.0 - 0.0) = 1.110e-13
```

and therefore significantly lower.

The downside is that 4 rand() calls will be needed to obtain the randomized integral number (assuming a 15 bit RNG).

```
double random_range (double const range_min, double const range_max)
{
  static unsigned long long const mant_mask53(9007199254740991);
  static double const i_to_d53(1.0/9007199254740992.0);
  unsigned long long const r( (unsigned long long(rand()) | (unsigned long long(rand()) << 15) | (unsigned long long(rand()) << 30) | (unsigned long long(rand()) << 45)) & mant_mask53 );
  return range_min + i_to_d53*double(r)*(range_max-range_min);
}
```

If the number of bits for the mantissa or the RNG is unknown the respective values need to be obtained within the function.

```
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
double random_range_p (double const range_min, double const range_max)
{
  static unsigned long long const num_mant_bits(numeric_limits<double>::digits), ll_one(1), 
    mant_limit(ll_one << num_mant_bits);
  static double const i_to_d(1.0/double(mant_limit));
  static size_t num_rand_calls, rng_bits;
  if (num_rand_calls == 0 || rng_bits == 0)
  {
    size_t const rand_max(RAND_MAX), one(1);
    while (rand_max > (one << rng_bits))
    {
      ++rng_bits;
    }
    num_rand_calls = size_t(ceil(double(num_mant_bits)/double(rng_bits)));
  }
  unsigned long long r(0);
  for (size_t i=0; i<num_rand_calls; ++i)
  {
    r |= (unsigned long long(rand()) << (i*rng_bits));
  }
  r = r & (mant_limit-ll_one);
  return range_min + i_to_d*double(r)*(range_max-range_min);
}
```

Note: I don't know whether the number of bits for unsigned long long (64 bit) is greater than the number of double mantissa bits (53 bit for  IEE 754) on all platforms or not.
It would probably be "smart" to include a check like `if (sizeof(unsigned long long)*8 > num_mant_bits) ...` if this is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

This snippet is straight from Stroustrup's [*The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)*](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), §40.7; it requires C++11:

```
#include <functional>
#include <random>

class Rand_double
{
public:
    Rand_double(double low, double high)
    :r(std::bind(std::uniform_real_distribution<>(low,high),std::default_random_engine())){}

    double operator()(){ return r(); }

private:
    std::function<double()> r;
};

#include <iostream>    
int main() {
    // create the random number generator:
    Rand_double rd{0,0.5};

    // print 10 random number between 0 and 0.5
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i){
        std::cout << rd() << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For generating random numbers we can use the methods that our other friends told. I want to add a very important point here.

The code told by others is :

```
//I have made this as a function that returns the random double value, just copy this
// if you want
double random(){
    return (double)rand() / RAND_MAX; // for generating random points between 0 to 1
}
//now suppose I want any random value between two numbers min and max then I can use this as :
int mynum = min + (max-min)*random();
```

But the problem with this code is that it is biased, I mean that it is not giving value equally between 0 and 1.
[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb1lM.png) This image shows how the value returned is more biased towards the center (i.e. is near value one). In order to avoid such condition we should prefer the following code:

```
double random(){
        return sqrt((double)rand() / RAND_MAX); // for generating random points between 0 to 1
    }
```

**Reason for choosing Square root function**

The reason for choosing sqrt() rather than any other functions like cbrt() to bias it towards the outer end is that in the first approach mentioned above, the points generated were proportional to R^2 because our random was proportional to R, thus making points overall area of the circle proportional to R^2 which made them concentrated more towards the center. Making our random proportional to sqrt(R) would make the points generated over all the area of the circle proportional to R which would make all the points generate uniformly throughout the circle.

Note that after applying sqrt (a point between [0, 1]), the result would be a value greater than the original random() thus making it biased more towards the outer end. This makes the point uniformly generated over all of the circle.

I would like to thank @archit91 for sharing this usefull information on LeetCode in [this article](https://leetcode.com/discuss/explore/march-leetcoding-challenge-2021/1113792/Generate-Random-Point-in-a-Circle-or-Short-and-Easy-w-Explanation-and-Diagrams)

Answer (score 2):

So many great solutions already and many are very elegant. I just figured I would add another to the list. I am drawing references directly from the 'Modern C++ Programming CookBook, 2nd edition'. In the chapter on random number generators, there is some emphasis on how very important it is to properly initialize the pseudo-random number generators. It adds that the  Mersenne twister engine has a bias towards producing some values repeatedly and not including other values therefore not generating numbers in a uniform distribution but more like a binomial or Poisson distribution. The snippet I am including goes through the steps of initializing a generator in order to produce pseudo-random numbers with a true uniform distribution.

```
auto generate_random_double(double lb, double ub)//lb= lowerbound, ub = upperbound
{
    //produce random #'s to be used as seeding values
    std::random_device rd{};

    //Generate random data for all the internal bits of the engine
    std::array<double, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data{};
    ranges::generate(seed_data,std::ref(rd));
    
    //Create an std::seed_seq object from the pseudo random data 
    std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
    
    //Create an engine object and initialize the bits representing the internal      
    //state of the engine; form example an mt19937 has 19937 bits
    auto eng = std::mt19937{ seq };

    //Create object based on the approprieat distribution based on application   
    //requirments 
    const auto randDouble = std::uniform_real_distribution<>{ lb,ub };

    //return object seeded with the previously initialized object
    return randDouble(eng);

}//end method generate_random_double
```

Comment: It appears that `std::ranges::generate` is available from C++20.

What would be the equivalent code with C++14 ?

Comment: @mcamurri, The code for how to do this in c++14 is on a github page that I  uploaded the code to, because I was not able to format the code in this comment section and make it look neat so I am just sharing the link to where you can find the code. `https://github.com/RyanZurrin/randomNumberTest/blob/master/main.cpp`

Comment: I also added a new answer below with the code, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a self-contained C++ class using C++11. It generates a random double within a half-open interval `[low, high)` (`low <= x < high`).

```c++
#include <random>

// Returns random double in half-open range [low, high).
class UniformRandomDouble
{
    std::random_device _rd{};
    std::mt19937 _gen{_rd()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> _dist;

    public:

        UniformRandomDouble() {
            set(1.0, 10.0);
        }
        
        UniformRandomDouble(double low, double high) {
            set(low, high);
        }

        // Update the distribution parameters for half-open range [low, high).
        void set(double low, double high) {
            std::uniform_real_distribution<double>::param_type param(low, high);
            _dist.param(param);
        }

        double get() {
            return _dist(_gen);
        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to my answer above but should work from C++11 and up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

/**
 * a function that will generate pseudo random numbers in a normal distribution
 * @param lb  is the lower bound of the distribution (inclusive)
 * @param ub  is the upper bound of the distribution (inclusive)
 * @return  a pseudo random number in the range [lb, ub]
 */
auto generate_random_double(double lb, double ub)
{
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::array<double, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data{};
    std::generate(seed_data.begin(), seed_data.end(), std::ref(rd));
    std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
    auto eng = std::mt19937{ seq };
    const auto randDouble = std::uniform_real_distribution<>{ lb,ub };
    return std::bind(randDouble, eng);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const long max_rand = 1000000L;
    double x1 = 12.33, x2 = 34.123, x;

    srandom(time(NULL));

    x = x1 + ( x2 - x1) * (random() % max_rand) / max_rand;

    cout << x1 << " <= " << x << " <= " << x2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "(random() % max_rand)" = "random()" (i.e. 3 % 7 = 3). This would be a wasted processing step.

Comment: @Zak: That would be true if it were using the standard constant `RAND_MAX`.... but it isn't.