# Create matrix with random binary element in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix in matlab with 500 cell (50 row,10 column ), How I can create and initialize it by random binary digits?
 I want some thing like this in 50*10 scale
as sample 3*4

0   1    1     1
0   0    0     0
1   1    1     1

and after it, how can get decimal equation of any row ? like row 1 is equal 7 in decimal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use `randi` to generate random integers?

```
A = randi([0 1], 50, 10);
```

and to convert a binary row to a number - as in the previous answers:

```
bin2dec(num2str(A(n,:)))
```

Comment: Because ints are ints, and bools are bools. It's always best to stick to type, even in Matlab :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis OP wanted binary digits, not *true* and *false*. That means numbers, not logical values.

Comment: Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) for the definition of a "binary digit" :) `true` and `false` are simply different words for `1` and `0`, respectively.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis you generate random doubles and cast them to logicals. Can I do the same, just using proper function for generations of random integers from [0 1]? I asked about using `randi` as opposed to `rand`. In your method, are both digits found with equal probability?

Comment: Yes, since `rand` chooses uniformly from `[0,1)`, the command `rand>0.5` returns a `true` or `false` with equal probability. Note that in C/C++ you'd generate random doubles [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c), wheras random ints are done like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/). Note also the remark a few lines down from the top of that last link. It's anyone's guess if the Mathworks have used C or Fortran for the implementation of `rand` and `randi`, but given these two links, `rand` seems a safer bet.

Comment: If you want logicals you'll have to cast them too: `logical(randi(...))`. You can cast, I have to compare -- you'll be faster :) BTW, in the past, you could have suggested `randint(50,10)`, a bit less versatile but cleaner in this context, but that's deprecated now...

Comment: ooh! Doing a speed test, my solution is (quite unexpectedly I have to say) almost 3 times faster than yours...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis [`rand` documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) and `rand` help both say that it chooses numbers from an open interval `(0,1)`, so I think you are wrong. About the cast, I would never bother to do it, since I do not care whether my 0/1 is expressed as 4 or 1 byte integers just to print them later. I would have to see some speed benefits, otherwise storage is just storage to me. About speed of `rand` vs. `randi`, you may well be right, I never checked. But in this case you did not convince me that the results are the same, so I go for correctness :)

Comment: How does the openness of the interval affect my statement? You're really nagging over 1 in 1/eps difference in probability?! Then the burden of proof now lies with you to show that randi does that differently (*demonstrate*, not link to te doc :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis cmon, it's Sunday:) I'm not nagging, and I don't want to prove it, because I don't really want to think about it every time I randomise integers. I play safe and hold mathworks responsible for their code and documentation. And I did show that 0 and 1 have different probability the way you do it, be it eps or not.. You may not care, I probably don't really care :) but maybe others do. It is useful to know the pitfalls. A loose analogy - recently scientists thought they found faster than light neutrinos. For some faulty time measurement device and a lost 60 ns. irrelevant,I know:)

Comment: Not sure why you think you *proved* it -- the situation is a lot more complicated, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0/). Anyway, doing a `sum(rand(1e8,1)>0.5)` and a `sum(randi([0 1],1e8,1))` a couple of hundred times and taking the mean shows that, aside from the factor ~2 speed difference, it seems that `randi` also tends more towards the `0`. But the tendency is so small, that if it really bothers someone, that someone should not be using pseudo-random numbers to begin with :p

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
A = rand(50, 10) > 0.5;
```

The decimal equivalent of the `n`th row is given by:

```
 bin2dec(num2str(A(n,:)))
```

or, if you prefer,

```
sum( A(n,:) .* 2.^(size(A,2)-1:-1:0) )   % for big endian
sum( A(n,:) .* 2.^(0:size(A,2)-1) )      % for little endian
```

which is several times faster than `bin2dec`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
 A=round(rand(50,10));
```

The decimal eq of the n-th row is given by:

```
 bin2dec(num2str(A(n,:)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Through the other answares are shorter I find it rather unappealing generating random numbers with 32 or 64 bit numbers and then throwing away 31 or 63 of them... and rather go with something like:

```
A_dec=randi([0,2^10-1],50,1,'uint16');
```

And to get the bits:

```
A_bin=bsxfun(@(a,i)logical(bitget(a,i)),A_dec,10:-1:1);
```

---

This is also several times faster for larger arrays (R2014a, i7 930)[but that doesn't seem to be of importance for the OP]:

> > tic; for i=1:1000;n = randi([0,2^10-1],50000,1,'uint16'); end;toc

```
Elapsed time is 1.341566 seconds.
```

> > tic; for i=1:1000;n =bsxfun(@(n,i)logical(bitget(n,i)),randi([0,2^10-1],50000,1,'uint16'),10:-1:1); end;toc

```
Elapsed time is 2.547187 seconds.
```

> > tic; for i=1:1000;n = rand(50000,10)>0.5; end;toc

```
Elapsed time is 8.030767 seconds.
```

> > tic; for i=1:1000;n = sum(bsxfun(@times,rand(50000,10)>0.5,2.^(0:9)),2); end;toc

```
Elapsed time is 13.062462 seconds.
```

`binornd` is even slower:

> > tic; for i=1:1000;n = logical(binornd(ones(50000,10),0.5)); end;toc

```
Elapsed time is 47.657960 seconds.
```

---

Note that this is still not optimal due to the way MATLAB saves logicals. (bits saved as bytes...)

Comment: Interesting idea. But doesn't this assume that the bits themselves are uniformly distributed? Is that true? Why is half of the `A_bin` matrix zeros?

Comment: Ups...I thought, because my system was little endian bitget would be counting beginning with the most significant bit, obviously it doesn't. - fixed now.

Comment: It does indeed assume that the bits are uniformly distributed which is the case if all the integer numbers form 0 to 2^nBits-1 are uniformly distributed. Not sure how well the ML random number generator generates unbiased pseudo random numbers and I guess the random numbers generated by the other approaches will be more independent but that really depends on the pseudo random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try it like this:

```
A = binornd(ones(50,10),p);
```

This way you also have the option to control the probability of occurrence of ones.