# random function which generates 1 or 0 with given probability

Tags: c++, random, probability

I need to implement a function int myRand(double p)
which return 1 or 0.The probability it will return `1` is `p` ,while the probability it will return `0` is `1- p`

Comment: And what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: you can use any libs for that or not?

Comment: In my opinion this question is not ambiguous, is not vague, is not incomplete, is not rhetorical. It is just seems to me a "do my homework" question. I can't answer because the question is currently closed. The hint to Yakov is to have a look at std::bernoulli_distribution in C++11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generate a random `double` in the range `[0..1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2704521/335858), and then do this:

```
int randomWithProb(double p) {
    double rndDouble = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return rndDouble > p;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) for this:

```
#include <random>

double p = 0.25;

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::discrete_distribution<> distrib({ 1-p, p });
                                    // ^^^  ^- probability for 1
                                    //  | probability for 0
std::cout << distrib(gen);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to generate a random flaot from [0,1]. If its >p then return 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It will return a 0 or a 1 with probabilities 1 and (1-p), respectively.  That's the complement of what was requested.