# I am having problems using absolute value in C

Tags: c

I am having a problem understanding something ...

Say I have a vector

```
double values[size];
```

And I want to count the number of non zeros values in it ...

```
int counter;
if(abs(counter) > 0.000001)
   ++counter;
```

However this doesn't return the same value of counter as

```
if(counter > 0.0000001 || counter < -0.000001)
```

Comment: Why are you checking `counter` against zero, and not `values[i]` where `i` is in `[0, size)`?

Comment: Suggest not using `abs()`.  `size_t counter = 0; for (size_t i = size; i > 0; ) { if (values[--i] != 0.0) counter++ }`

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong function. `abs()` returns an integer value. You really want to use the `fabs()` function. In your code, the decimal portion of the number is completely lost, due to integer truncation.

Second, you can just compare the value against 0.0. In ANSI C, and according to C99, you can have both positive 0.0 and negative 0.0, but equivalence operator checks (ie: `==`) will still report they are equal/equivalent.

Finally, the use of the absolute value function here is kind of overkill. The only reason you'd really need to use it is if you want to calculate if the values in your array are "close enough" to zero.

**Trivial Case - Is it zero?**

**Sample Code**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax) {
   double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
   return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

int main(void) {
   int i;
   int nZeroes = 0;
   int nElements = 20;
   double* lfArray;
   if ((lfArray = calloc(nElements, sizeof(double))) == NULL) {
      /* Memory error, abort */
      return (-1);
   }

   /* Populate array */
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      lfArray[i] = fRand(-10.0, +10.0);
   }
   /* Set a few arbitrary elements to 0.0 */
   lfArray[5] = 0.0;
   lfArray[10] = 0.0;
   lfArray[15] = 0.0;

   /* Determine how many zeroes are present, and log the results */
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      if (fabs(lfArray[i]) == 0.0) {
         nZeroes++;
      }
   }
   printf("Number of zeroes detected:%d\n", nZeroes);
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      printf("Element:%02d, Value:%3.4lf\n", i, lfArray[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
Number of zeroes detected:3
Element:00, Value:-9.9998
Element:01, Value:-7.3692
Element:02, Value:5.1121
Element:03, Value:-0.8270
Element:04, Value:0.6553
Element:05, Value:0.0000
Element:06, Value:-9.0591
Element:07, Value:3.5773
Element:08, Value:3.5859
Element:09, Value:8.6939
Element:10, Value:0.0000
Element:11, Value:0.3883
Element:12, Value:6.6193
Element:13, Value:-9.3086
Element:14, Value:-8.9308
Element:15, Value:0.0000
Element:16, Value:3.4230
Element:17, Value:-9.8460
Element:18, Value:-2.3317
Element:19, Value:-8.6632
```

**Non-Trivial Case - Are we "close enough" to zero?**

**Sample Code - Case 2**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double fRand(double fMin, double fMax) {
   double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
   return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}

int main(void) {
   int i;
   float lowerLimit = -0.001;
   float upperLimit = +0.001;
   int nZeroes = 0;
   int nElements = 20;
   double* lfArray;
   if ((lfArray = calloc(nElements, sizeof(double))) == NULL) {
      /* Memory error, abort */
      return (-1);
   }

   /* Populate array */
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      lfArray[i] = fRand(2.0*lowerLimit, 2.0*upperLimit);
   }

   /* Determine how many zeroes are present, and log the results */
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      if (fabs(lfArray[i]) < upperLimit) {
         lfArray[i] = 0.0;
         nZeroes++;
      }
   }
   printf("Number of zeroes detected:%d\n", nZeroes);
   for (i=0; i<nElements; i++) {
      printf("Element:%02d, Value:%3.4lf\n", i, lfArray[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output - Case 2**

---

```
Number of zeroes detected:9
Element:00, Value:-0.0020
Element:01, Value:-0.0015
Element:02, Value:0.0010
Element:03, Value:0.0000
Element:04, Value:0.0000
Element:05, Value:-0.0011
Element:06, Value:-0.0018
Element:07, Value:0.0000
Element:08, Value:0.0000
Element:09, Value:0.0017
Element:10, Value:0.0000
Element:11, Value:0.0000
Element:12, Value:0.0013
Element:13, Value:-0.0019
Element:14, Value:-0.0018
Element:15, Value:0.0000
Element:16, Value:0.0000
Element:17, Value:-0.0020
Element:18, Value:0.0000
Element:19, Value:-0.0017
```

**References**

---

1. *Double `fabs()`*, Accessed 2014-03-28, [`<http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/)
2. *Generate random double number*, Accessed 2014-03-28, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c)
3. *Truncation*, Accessed 2014-03-28, [`<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation)