# auto f = bind(dist<>,gen) fails in C++ member declaration. Not recognized as a function

Tags: c++, std

Some example code in Stroustrup's "C++ Programming Language" fails to compile using GCC 6.4.1 std=C11.

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>

// From Stroustrup C++11 4th Edition section 40.7
// error: non-static data member declared ‘auto’
class Rand_int {
public:    // public: Added to text from original
    Rand_int(int lo, int hi) : p{lo,hi} { }
    int operator()() const { return r(); }
private:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type p;
    auto r = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<>{p},std::default_random_engine{});
};
```

The compiler fails with "error: non-static data member declared ‘auto’". Hence it sees this definition as that of a data member and not a member function. The return from bind is supposed to allow declaration auto.

This quote from Stroustrup follows immediately after the code above "I store the parameters using the distribution’s standard param_type alias (§40.7.3) so that I can use
auto to avoid having to name the result of the bind() ."

`default_random_engine` is a `typedef` of a stdlib template function. How to fix?

Comment: You define data member and it is unclear why you expect that to be member function declaration.

Comment: The example [from the 4th edition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016865/2672107) looks different.

Comment: `auto f = bind(dist<>,gen)` in the title can nit be found in your code.

Comment: Btw `std::bind` returns functor, not function. But even if you put a function on right side of `auto r =` it would make r pointer to a function, not a function.

Comment: @manni66 I mislabeled the section from Stroustrup. My example is found directly above the Rand_double example you cited. Btw, Rand_double compiles just fine. It also does not use auto to declare the return from a member function.

Answer (score 1):

> Hence it sees this definition as that of a data member and not a member function.

You have couple issues with this approach:

- `std::bind()` returns a "function object" aka functor, not function

From [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) documentation:

> A function object of unspecified type T, for which std::is_bind_expression::value == true

- even if you put a function on the right side of assignment it would not make it a function

For example:

```
 void foobar();
 auto r = foobar;
```

this would make `r` a pointer to function `foobar()` with type `void (*)();` not a function. It is not possible to declare a method or standalone function this way. The fact, that later in code you can call it like a function with `r();` does not make that a function.