# How do I generate a random double between 0 and max (in C)?

Tags: c, random

Here's what I did to generate the random double:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    double max = 10.0;
    double x = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/max);

    printf("The random number is %f \n", x);
}
```

Although the number this generates is random in nature, it's still not random enough.

The first time I ran this, I got 7.303385
Then I got 7.320475.
Then I got 7.332377.
Then I got 7.345195.

You get the idea. It look like my code is only generating random numbers between 7.3 and 7.4.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Another weird thing I just noticed:

I changed up my code a little:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    double max = 10.0;
    double x = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/max);
    double y = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/max);

    printf("The random number is %f \n", x);
    printf("The random number is %f \n", y);
}
```

When I run this, x always gives me a value between 7.3 and 7.4 so no change here. However, y always generates between 0 and 10, which is what I want. So why is x behaving differently?

Comment: What happens if you remove `srand(time(NULL));` ?

Comment: There are *many* tutorials all over the Internet, and many questions here about getting a number in a range (like e.g. `0` to `10`). Please do some searching first.

Comment: By the way, are you doing all this inside a loop? Including the `srand` call? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Jabberwocky When I remove that, x is always 0.012513 and y is always 5.635853. No matter how many times I run it, x and y always has those values. So it's not even random anymore.

Comment: Make sure you call `srand()` once. I had some code for uniformly generating random numbers [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/random-numbers-%e2%88%88min-max/), but as that dude said, there are plenty in the Internet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No this isn't in a loop. It only runs 1 time in the main() function.

Comment: @BobK please show a [mcve]. Without `srand(time(NULL));` your code runs more or less fine.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need the casts. Because `max` is of type `double` then the result of `RAND_MAX / max` will be a `double` as well. And because of that the second division will also be of type `double`. So only `rand() / (RAND_MAX / max)` is really enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate random double numbers in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c), see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704552/4892907

Comment: OK, it's much clearer now. I can reproduce your issue more or less with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, but not here: https://onlinegdb.com/rkov3gWMN. What is your platform? It looks like a poor implementation of `srand` to me. This also illustrates the problem: https://onlinegdb.com/HJaj6lZGE. The numbers don't look random at all with Visual Studio but they do on other platforms.

Comment: what's the output of `srand(1546932298); printf("%d\n", rand()); printf("%d\n", rand()); srand(1546932299); printf("%d\n", rand()); printf("%d\n", rand());` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code looks like, but this works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));    // call srand once only

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {
//  srand(time(NULL));  // don't put srand here

    double max = 10.0;

    double x = (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX / max);
    double y = (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX / max);

    printf("The random number is %f \n", x);
    printf("The random number is %f \n", y);
  }
}
```

Different problem:

You probably want `RAND_MAX/max;` instead of `(double)(RAND_MAX/max);`, otherwise you may run into problems if `max` is large.

Comment: Yeah that does work. But why didn't it work properly when it was wasn't inside of a loop? Why was x always between 7.3 and 7.4?

Comment: You probably included the `srand()` call inside the loop. Don't do that. You should only initialize the RNG once.

Comment: I'm confused ... the op (Bob K) mentioned in a comment that this was not run in a loop (although a similar effect could be present if the binary is run repeatedly without much delay), but then User95 (I'm assuming a relation with the op) implies there was a loop.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes it was certainly in a loop. OP probably misunderstood the comment.

Comment: @User95 it didn't work properly because [`time`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) returns the number of seconds elapsed since since 00:00 hours, Jan 1, 1970. Therefore successive calls to `srand(time())` within one second will seed the random number generator with the same number over and over again and therefore calls to `rand` will result in the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. User95 is more of a personal account and this is my work account. I might have accidentally logged in with my personal account before writing my comment.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Also I never mentioned that my code was placed in a loop. You might have misunderstood me. My code was only place in the main() function without any loops. That's when I was having the issues. But when I tested the code in this answer (which is in a loop), it worked.

Comment: @BobK it's quite unclear what your issue is. Could you your question and post a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem? YOu have been asked to do this multiple times already.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've already stated multiple times that I'm running the code in the main function. I've updated the description. My issue is that I'm not 100% sure about why the value of x isn't completely random.

Comment: @BobK your code in the edited question looks fine and it works as expected: https://www.ideone.com/S3JHNL. Did you include `<stdio.h>` and `<time.h>`?