# how is this for random number generation

Tags: c++, random

so in my custom C++ library i wanted to create 2 reliable and simple functions, i for quickly generating a random number, and the other for doing the same thing but within a specified range, i came up with the following but would like to know if they are good:

```
int random()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>dist;
    return dist(rd);
}

int randomWithinRange(int range)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>dist;
    return (dist(rd) % range);
}
```

the functions work and compile alright, i just want to know how good they would be for long term inclusion

Comment: What do you mean *long term inclusion*?

Comment: Not good enough. No need to create random device every time, it's quite heavy operation and can be deterministic, so you can received the same number sequence. % range can be replaced with dist(0, range).

Comment: You should not really be using `std::random_device` to do anything except seed a pseudo random number generator. Here is an example, but it depends on your situation the best technique to employ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c/35687575#35687575