# range function like python but for C++ 17 (double)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

I'm trying to create a function that fills my vector with values from beginning to end with a certain step. For type double and C++ 17 version. Any idea how to do this?

```
vector<double> generateRange(double start, double end, double step)
{


}

int main()
{
    // return [10, 10.5, 11,...., 12]
    auto range = generateRange(10, 12, 0.5);

    for (auto i : range)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

For int it would be a very simple loop, but for double...

Comment: Check the example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator

Comment: You say it would be a simple loop for int. Can you show what that would look like and describe what you think would be the sticking points adapting it to work for doubles?

Comment: @nathan-pierson Because floating-point numbers represent real numbers, it is often mistakenly assumed that they can represent any simple fraction exactly. We can use double in for loop.

Comment: Here is some more info: 
There are some nice random generators available. Just use vector's push_back to add the numbers to the vector. you'r mainloop should work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c
https://www.johndcook.com/blog/cpp_TR1_random/

Comment: Given that you could write this for `int`, I suspect that if you **tried** writing the same for `double`, you would either succeed or have a _more specific_ question about why your code isn't perfect.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to decide what happens if the value you're using as a step size doesn't exactly divide the range you're dividing, or isn't exactly representable as a double. What would you _want_ the result of `generateRange(0, 1, (1.0/3))` to be? Or `generateRange(0, 1, 0.3)`, for that matter?

Comment: @nathan-pierson I hadn't thought about that question. But I think it would be cool to have a bool option like round down or round up

Comment: Try thinking through what your desired output is. Try to write up an implementation that produces it. If you have problems, ask about those specific issues.

Comment: The most accurate way to calculate value at index `i` is not to add `step` to the previous value, but doing `val= start + i * step`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example write a simple loop to generate vector that you want.

However, the `range` function in python doesn't return a list but a generator, which is much faster. You should be returning a generator (range) in C++ as well instead of returning a vector. Implementing a generator is a bit more advanced.

The standard library comes with tools that can be used to build such generator. Here is your example:

```
auto step_fun = [=](auto x) { return x * step + start; };
auto end_pred = [=](auto x) { return x <= end; };
auto range =
    std::views::iota(0)
    | std::views::transform(step_fun)
    | std::views::take_while(end_pred);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you absolutely need to store the values in a vector before iterating over them.

I would do something like this

```cpp
/**
  g++ -std=c++17 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

inline
auto // iterable
generate_range(double from_count,
               double to_count,
               double step)
{
  struct Iter
  {
    double count;
    double step;
    bool operator!=(const double &rhs) const { return count<=rhs; } // oh!!!
    void operator++() { count+=step; }
    auto operator*() const { return count; }
  };
  struct Enumerate
  {
    double from_count;
    double to_count;
    double step;
    auto begin() { return Iter{from_count, step}; }
    auto end() { return to_count; }
  };
  return Enumerate{std::min(from_count, to_count),
                   std::max(from_count, to_count),
                   step};
}

int
main()
{
  for(const auto &value: generate_range(10, 12, 0.5))
  {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n'; // 10 10.5 11 11.5 12
  for(const auto &value: generate_range(239.99, 237.36, 1))
  {
    std::cout << value << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n'; // 237.36 238.36 239.36
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `!=` actually tests `<=`; it's ugly, but it works.

This function returns something that offers `begin()` and `end()` member-functions so that a range-for loop can use it.

**edit**: added min/max for inverted bounds.

Comment: thx so much, but i try this data and it doesn't work: generate_range(239.99, 237.36, 1) I expected to see 238 But the program did not display anything

Comment: Ah, you want it to go backwards too?

Comment: @SergoLongid I edited consequently, but I'm not certain of what you precisely expect.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to problem:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#include <algorithm>

vector<double> generateRange(double start, double end, double step)
{
    int vector_size = (end - start) / step;
    vector<double> values(vector_size);
    std::for_each(begin(values), std::end(values),
    [start, step, i = 0](double &actual) mutable {
        actual = start + step * i;
        i++;
    });
    return values;

}

int main()
{
    // return [10, 10.5, 11,...., 12]
    auto range = generateRange(10, 12, 0.5);

    for (auto i : range)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

if you have any question about functions i used don't hesitate to ask :)