# templating a random number generator in c++

Tags: c++, templates, random, distribution

I know my code is wrong. I should have `uniform_int_distribution<int>`, but I need a random number generator that works whatever the type is.
I mean I could generate int and divide them by `10^n` to get a float but I dont like the elegance of it.

```cpp
template <class T>
T aleaGenVal(const T &min,const T &max)
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(min,max);
    return dist(rng);
}
```

thank you for your help

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: You need to specialise the template function depending on the traits of `T`. E.g. use `uniform_real_distribution` in a particular specialisation.

Comment: What should be the result of `aleaGenVal<std::string>("one", "2")`? What about `aleaGenVal<mylib::BigInt>(1, 1e1000)`?

Comment: My question is : How do I make my function aleaGenVal to generates number depending the type T ?
I already tried `uniform_real_distribution<T>` but it returns me an error saying it needs to be a float type

Comment: what distribution do you want when `T` is not integer? You only explained what you dont want

Comment: I want to generates random int and random float only using 1 function

Comment: Here is a solution, not so much a duplicate question though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704521/generate-random-double-numbers-in-c/35687575#35687575

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::uniform_int_distribution` is only defined for some fundamental integer types, and `std::uniform_real_distribution` is only defined for the fundamental floating point types.

You could choose between those with [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

Unfortunately there are a number of integral types that are not usable with `std::uniform_int_distribution`, so we have to enumerate the allowed ones.

```
template <typename> struct has_uniform_distribution : std::false_type;

template <std::floating_point T> struct has_uniform_distribution<T> : std::true_type;

template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<short> : std::true_type;
template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<unsigned short> : std::true_type;

template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<int> : std::true_type;
template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<unsigned int> : std::true_type;

template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<long> : std::true_type;
template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<unsigned long> : std::true_type;

template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<long long> : std::true_type;
template <> struct has_uniform_distribution<unsigned long long> : std::true_type;

template <typename T>
concept uniform_distribution = has_uniform_distribution<T>::value;

template <uniform_distribution T> // or sfinae over has_uniform_distribution in C++ earlier than C++20
T aleaGenVal(T min, T max)
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());

    using dist_t = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_integral_v<T>, 
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T>, 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T>
    >;

    dist_t dist(min,max);
    return dist(rng);
}

template <typename T>
T aleaGenVal(T min, T max) = delete;
```

Alternatively, we could define it for all arithmetic types, by using the widest generator type, and narrowing the result

```
template <std::arithmetic T> // or sfinae over std::is_arithmetic in C++ earlier than C++20
T aleaGenVal(T min, T max)
{
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());

    using dist_t = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_integral_v<T>, 
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_signed_v<T>, 
            std::uniform_int_distribution<long long>, 
            std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long>> 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>;

    dist_t dist(min,max);
    return static_cast<T>(dist(rng));
}
```

Comment: You can let `T` free (or take both floating-point/integral) and select the right template in `aleaGenVal`. That would avoid duplication of the function body.

Comment: `std::is_integral` is not a sufficient condition to use `std::uniform_int_distribution`. You can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution#:~:text=Template%20parameters-,IntType,.,-Member%20types) that `bool` and `char` for example may not be used (undefined behaviour). We would need kind of a [`is_strict_integral`](https://github.com/merlin-source-libraries/Merlin-type-traits/blob/44fb746bc2e266d0376eee0e0b74c82e8debb675/include/merlin_type_traits.hpp#L14-L19) type trait to be compliant.

Comment: @Fareanor I would rather say that `std::arithmetic` is not a sufficient constraint.

Comment: @Fareanor or we can widen the integral types

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works well for me (with C++17):

```
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename R = std::mt19937_64>
T random(const T& min, const T& max)
{
  R rng{std::random_device{}()};
  if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    return dist(rng);

  } else if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(min, max);
    return dist(rng);
  } else {
    // If T is unsupported type...
    return T{};
  }
}
```

An example of use with Google bench: https://github.com/bensuperpc/vector/blob/c7fd274be0c667009bba3c150fd5c8082496bbc4/test/source/random_bench.cpp#L12